# How many XD will be printed?

Tags: c, linux, buffer, stdout

I ran into this weird problem when I was playing with fork() with one of my friend.
Very simple POC code likes:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
        printf("xd\n");
        fork();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I got a pretty output:

`xd
xd
xd
xd
xd
xd
xd
xd
xd
xd
xd
xd
xd
xd
xd`

xd has been printed for 15 times, which is what I expected - the number of nodes in a 4 level complete binary tree.
But, when we removed the "\n" in printf, we got another completely different result:

`xdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxdxd`

It gave me 64 XDs (my friend got 56 XDs on his machine). This seems to be a somewhat "stable" result as I could run it many times and it give me the same result (same as my friend's).

I tried to change printf("xd") into perror("xd"), it gave me 15 outputs:

`xd: Success
xd: Success
xd: Success
xd: Success
xd: Success
xd: Success
xd: Success
xd: Success
xd: Success
xd: Success
xd: Success
xd: Success
xd: Success
xd: Success
xd: Success`

And I tried

```
    for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
        printf("xd");
        fflush(stdout);
        fork();
    }
```

This will give me 15 XDs in one line. 
I bet this has something to do with output buffer, but I can't explain this. 
I have two naive guesses, one is consider it as classic concurrency issue, but I denied it very soon as fork() creates another process instead of thread, each child process actually holding different copy of i. (Please correct me if I'm wrong) 
Another naive guess would be, when multiple processes writing into the same stdout, right after the contents in buffer has been displayed on screen but before been cleaned out from the buffer, if another process write something into the buffer, it will stop clean it / consider the whole buffer as valid. 
Both these two are very likely to be wrong as I know very little about the Linux implementations, could anyone please help me explaining it?

Comment: Just try to test it by printing following `printf("%d : %d xd\n", i, getpid());` this way you'll get into whats going on, as you'll see what value `i` is printed by which process

Comment: hah, your exactly right, copied from the OP's example wrongly ;)

Comment: @mafso You're right, it should be printf("xd"); sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are following is because of buffering mode.

Because there is no newline at the end and the output is running in line-buffered mode (or 
full-buffered mode) thats why the output you see is different

You have to use `fflush(0);` to empty all I/O buffers before forking

You can control the buffering mode by the Standard C function `setvbuf()` and the `_IOFBF` (full buffering), `_IOLBF` (line buffering) and `_IONBF` (no buffering) modes.

Answer (score 1):

the stdout is linebuffered, so on the first version all `printf`s will be printed immediately:

```
i=0: 1 xd
i=1: 2 xd
i=2: 4 xd
i=3: 8 xd
in sum: 15 xd
```

on the other side without the `\n` the stdout buffer will be copied with every `fork()` and so doubling the xd count.

```
i=0:  1 xd, after fork  2 xd and  2 processes
i=1:  4 xd, after fork  8 xd and  4 processes
i=2: 12 xd, after fork 24 xd and  8 processes
i=3: 32 xd, after fork 64 xd and 16 processes
```

at the end of the main process all 64 xd will be printed.

Comment: You mean each fork() will copy the stdout if we do not clear it explicitely? That's interesting.

Comment: @hzchen yes, the forked process will have the same state and variables as the parent process, so it will also have the same content in his stdout buffer. So it will be printed twice.